# Do achievements in Google Play Services sync across multiple Android devices?

Tags: android, google-play-services

If a player logged into Google Play Services on one Android device unlocks an achievement in a game, will that achievement also unlock on the player's second device when he/she returns to it?

If so, does it require calling GameClient's loadAchievements() method with forceReload set to true?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Achievements are device-independent, and are tied to the Player.

For loading the achievements (on whatever device) (after the Achievement has been unlocked) when you load the AchievementBuffer with the onAchievementsLoaded listener, the Achievement will show as unlocked.

If your player goes to a second device, and happens to already be in the game, would need to have a call to that listener triggered when un-pausing, as I know of no callback to say that Achievements have been updated.